# Getting related models in template

Tags: django

I've got two models. I'm attempted to get a qs of jobs for a given review within my template

**Models.py**

```
    class Job(models.Model):
        employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) 
        cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name="cartmodel",  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) 

    class Review(models.Model)
         cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

**views.py**

```
reviews = Review.objects.all()
```

**template**

```
{% for review in reviews %}
    {% for i in review.cart.job_set.all %}

        {{i.employee}}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The code in my template isn't working. Any thoughts how to correctly build this set in my template ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified as `related_name='cartmodel'`, that means you access the related `Job`s with `review.cart.cartmodel.all`, but the `related_name='cartmodel'` is likely a misnomen: this is the name of the `ForeignKey` in reverse, so you might want to rename this to:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    cart = models.ForeignKey(
        Cart,
        related_name='jobs',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

then you can thus render this with:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
    {% for i in review.cart.jobs.all %}
        {{ i.employee }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is also strange that the foreign keys are (both) NULLable, this means that `i.employee` can be `None`, and thus not point to a real employee.

You can optimize querying by prefetching the `cart` and jobs with:

```
reviews = Review.objects.select_related('cart').prefetch_related('cart__jobs')
```